# Resume Question: How do you put mastering out of PhD on resume?

Tags: phd, masters, cv, all-but-dissertation

I am currently in my 2nd year in a PhD and going to master out in May. Should I put "leaving PhD" on my resume? Or just Masters? My field is in Computer Science where mastering out is quite common.

Comment: Does "mastering out" mean getting an MPhil rather than a PhD? (Note that an MPhil is somewhat different from an MSc.)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to list the degrees you have earned. You don't need to list or mention the ones you haven't.

But be prepared to be honest in any interview in which you are asked. There are a lot of reasons for leaving any degree program.

In any application process stress the skills you have and your suitability for the position.